# Cant use brother methods with virtual inheritance cpp

Tags: c++, inheritance

> Because of virtual inheritance, when the write() function from the
>   transmitter class is called, the method read() from the receiver class
>   gets called (as you may have noticed, the transmitter class doesn't
>   have a read() function). In the above hierarchy we can instantiate
>   only the radio class because transmitter and receiver are abstract due
>   to virtual inheritance.
>   http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

So I tried it and it didnt worked for me.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

father class:

```
class father
{
public:
    father(){

    };
    ~father(){};

    virtual void printt() = 0;

    void sett()
    {
        printt();
    }
    void father()
    {
        cout << "Im your father...";
    }
private:
};
```

Person:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "father.h"

class MyClasst: public virtual father
{
public:
    MyClasst(){
        g = 8;
    };
    ~MyClasst(){};

    void print()
    {
        cout << "a";
    }
    void c()
    {
        cout << "bbb";
    }
private:
 ...
};
```

Student class:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "father.h"
using namespace std;


class MyClassa: public virtual father
{
public:
    MyClassa(){

    };
    ~MyClassa(){};

    void printt()
    {
        cout << "b";
    }
    void b()
    {
        c();
        printt();
    }
private:
...
};
```

By the rules above, I should be able to call 'c()' from person class in 'b()' ('b()' is function of Student which is virtual brother of 'Person class').
But I get an error:

> Error 1   error C3861: 'c': identifier not
>   found c:\users\micha\onedrive\מסמכים\visual studio
>   2013\projects\project7\project7\student.h 21  1   Project7

Comment: The virtual inheritance solves the problems generated by multiple inheritance from brother classes. You have the brother classes (`Myclassa` and `Myclasst` but I cannot see any class that inherits from both of them (there is no class that inherits from any of them at all). Maybe the [drawing in this article](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond) helps you understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the "`c()`" function is not declared in the base class "`father`" and your class "`MyClassa`" derives only from "`father`".
Consequently, an object of class "`MyClassa`" will not contain any function "`c()`".
An object of a class deriving from "`MyClasst`" (as well as an object deriving from both "`MyClassa`" and "`MyClasst`" will have it).
If you want to have your code compiling, you must add a declaration of "`c()`" in the parent class. Add the line "`virtual void c() = 0;`" in the class "`father`" - then will compile. Live example here: http://rextester.com/OBBC17077

Comment: I know it can be by that way you suggest. but where I looked in here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html I saw that virtual inheritance gives me the possibility to use "brother" methods without having them in the shared "father". so __MyClassa__ should be able to use __MyClasst__ 'c()' method because they both drived from the same father with virtual inheritance

Comment: @lkjlkjlkj The example uses a class (`radio`) which inherits from both siblings, and uses only virtual functions from their common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `c()` in `MyClassa` directly nor inherited from `father`. There is a method `c()` in `MyClasst`, but the two classes have no relation apart from inheriting both from `father`, but that doesnt allow them to call methods from each other.

Imho the analogy with the so called "parent class" and "child classes" does not make much sense and only leads to confusion. It doesnt make sense to say "a child is-a parent", but thats what (public) inheritance actually is. I would advice you to forget about the term "brother class". It doesnt help you to understand anything. And btw the error you get has little to do with the `virtual` inheritance. You would get the same error with `public` inheritance.

Comment: I know it can be by that way you suggest. but where I looked in here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html I saw that virtual inheritance gives me the possibility to use "brother" methods without having them in the shared "father". so __MyClassa__ should be able to use __MyClasst__ 'c()' method because they both drived from the same father with virtual inheritance

Comment: @lkjlkjlkj you must have misunderstood something. Can you point me to the exact part of the text where it says "brother classes" could call each others methods? The tutorial is rather long and I didnt find it

Comment: "Because of virtual inheritance, when the write() function from the transmitter class is called, the method read() from the receiver class gets called (as you may have noticed, the transmitter class doesn't have a read() function)."  this are two different classes which have this two different methods and they both sibilings of the same "father" named 'storable '

Comment: @lkjlkjlkj That example is incomplete, it has lots of `...`. And note that in that example, all classes inherit from `storable` that has a `write()` method declared, but your `father` has no method `c()`.